Are questions about issues with MIME Types on-topic?
I can't ask questions on StackoverFlow, because I'm not the greatest at asking questions. I'm getting better so I'll be able to fix my questions soon, but in the mean time, I'll ask here. I am having an issue with MIME type on JavaScript. Is that allowed and on topic on Software Engineering? I don't see why not, but still good to check up on you guys to make sure I don't get into trouble.

This question is similar to: Let's help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It would be helpful if you posted your question here, but I'm having trouble imagining such a question that would be on-topic here. Unless it's more of a conceptual design question, it sounds like it would be more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Sorry, forgot a bit of an important detail. I added that information on my question.

@Alex Not being able to ask on Stack Overflow doesn't mean you can ask here. In fact, it'll probably just lead you to being blocked from asking questions here, too. If you actually share the question you want to ask, I can give a more definitive answer if it would be on-topic here or not.

That would make sense. In short, my question goes, "How can I change the MIME type?"

My issue is that a library I'm importing doesn't work, because the MIME type is incorrect. I want to know how to fix that.

@Alex, that question belongs squarely at StackOverflow. You will not be doing yourself a favor by posting it here.

I'm trying to fix my answers on StackOverflow. Thanks. I'll do that
